# Retrieving an image from mysql with codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have set up a table in mysql to store my images via upload into a blob.  I am trying to display / show those images, but not sure how to do so in codeigniter.

Can someone make a suggestion on the best route / technique to do so?  If there is a link to read up on this, I have been unable to find more information.

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you just store the URL to the image ?

Comment: i was trying to research that too.  which is a better method?  how do you automate that process?  Is there a way to create a form that uploads the image and stores it in a folder and at the same time stores the path in mysql?

Comment: My personal preference is to keep my database as small as possible for performance and backup reasons.

Comment: understood.  is there any documentation on how to create a form that will upload the image to a specific directory (you designate) and then also store the image path?

Comment: Check out this [documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html)

Comment: http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/441314/upload-image-and-save-url-to-db-mysql

Answer (score 0):

You can Use CI built in Upload Class for this purpose , also you can store the image path in your database by using a model along with this class.

Secondly , storing the image path in database is a much better option.

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

EDIT :

`$this->upload->data();` this will return you the array containing all the info of your uploaded file, you can retrieve the data from this and then can use it to store the file info .

```
$data = $this->upload->data(); 
print_r($data);
```

Try this , to viee all the info of your uploaded file.

Comment: and do you upload all of your sites images to one folder and just call on them from your database or are you setting up unique folder names depending on what the image(s) is being used for?

Comment: Go through the link , there are options, to specify where you want the files to be uploaded.

Comment: So I was able to store the images using the File Uploading Class, however, how do I call and store the variables for the array with the info about the image (file_name, full_path, etc...)?